# Save multiple arrays to CSV from PHP

Tags: php, csv

There are two arrays that I'd like to save as CSV file from PHP. The problem is that this code works only for the first Call. E.g. in the below-given example I can save only `array1`, but `array2` is not saved. If I swap places of `array1` and `array2`, then `array2` will be saved instead of `array1`. What's actually wrong in my code and how could I solve this problem?

```
     header("Content-type: text/csv");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     $headers = array('xxx','yyy','zzz');
     saveCSV($array1,"file1.csv",$headers);

     header("Content-type: text/csv");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     $headers = array('aaa','bbb','ccc');   
     saveCSV($array2,"file2.csv",$headers);

function saveCSV($data,$fileName,$headers) {
    $outstream = fopen($fileName, "a");
    file_put_contents($fileName, "");

    if ($headers != 0)
        fputcsv($outstream,$headers);

    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals);
    }
    array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting the headers, twice.

Trying building up your csv data output, then once completed set the headers once.

Also you have a function declaration within another, which i'm sure is invalid.

move __outputCSV somwehere else, or maybe you intended it to be a closure?

Comment: move __outputCSV - this was the case

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only set headers once then return content.  The code above sets some headers, replies with CSV, then sets headers again, and replies with a different CSV again.   PHP/browser won't handle separate return.

Instead of pushing multiple miles from the server, perhaps you can just have the browser window.open() /path-to-get-csv-script.php?op=file1     and then op=file2.  The browser can then open up both files if that's what you want....